# Is there a way of programatically restarting an Android application

Tags: android

I have an application that is distributed into a series of apps. I would like to provide users with a method of clearing their user data. To do this I would like each app to clear it's user data. I have this part working correctly.

My question is, once I have cleared the user data, is there a way of restarting the applications, so that the restored settings take effect?

Comment: Why can't you just `finish()` and `startActivity()` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://goo.gl/0q5Tq) blog post by Jan Jonas offers a good explanation of how to restart an application programatically.

The approach is to create a restart intent, and add it to the alarm manager, with a time offset (so that it doesn't happen immediately.

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)ACTIVITY.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, RESTART_INTENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: idk why this never works for me :(. I deleted the data of the app, then call this, but the restore doesn't take effect. I got to go Home and kill the app myself.